# What is the difference between an object and instance?

Tags: oop

I just want to know what is the difference between an object and instance with example.

Answer (score 1):

An object is a software bundle of related state and behavior. A class is a blueprint or prototype from which objects are created. An instance is a single and unique unit of a class.

read more :[Class vs Object vs Instance](http://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/)

Answer (score 1):

Often the words *instance* and *object* are synonyms. Read more about [objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29)

Some languages (e.g. Smalltalk, Common Lisp, and even [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) are [reifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29) their classes, by having classes instances of meta-classes. In that case, you might say that these class objects are not instance (but it is a matter of terminology and context).

In other languages (e.g. C++) classes are not objects, e.g. because they make only sense at compile-time.

Some object oriented languages (e.g. JavaScript or [Self](http://selflanguage.org/)) don't have classes but [prototypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Answer (score 0):

As has been already mentioned, a class is a blueprint/recipe for creating objects. Hence,

1. A class is a blueprint for creating objects of that class.
2. On the reverse side, an object is an instance of that class.

"Object" is a runtime concept, it exists while running. That is when, for example in Java,
when the program execution reaches a statement where is says

```
ClassA objA = new ClassA();
```

it is then that an object of that class is created, or ***instantiated***. In the above code, objA is an instance of ClassA.